# yocto warning base-passwd failed to fetch URL

Tags: bash, bitbake, ubuntu-22.04, yocto-recipe

```
WARNING: base-passwd-3.5.29-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL https://launchpad.net/debian/+archive/primary/+files/base-passwd_3.5.29.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
```

Poky's branch is kirkstone.
The content file is:

```
SUMMARY = "Base system master password/group files"
DESCRIPTION = "The master copies of the user database files (/etc/passwd and /etc/group).  The update-passwd tool is also provided to keep the system databases synchronized with these master files."
HOMEPAGE = "https://launchpad.net/base-passwd"
SECTION = "base"
LICENSE = "GPL-2.0-only"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=eb723b61539feef013de476e68b5c50a"

RECIPE_NO_UPDATE_REASON = "Version 3.5.38 requires cdebconf for update-passwd utility"

SRC_URI = "https://launchpad.net/debian/+archive/primary/+files/${BPN}_${PV}.tar.gz \
           file://add_shutdown.patch \
           file://nobash.patch \
           file://noshadow.patch \
           file://input.patch \
           file://disable-docs.patch \
           file://kvm.patch \
           file://disable-shell.patch \
           "

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6beccac48083fe8ae5048acd062e5421"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "f0b66388b2c8e49c15692439d2bee63bcdd4bbbf7a782c7f64accc55986b6a36"

# the package is taken from launchpad; that source is static and goes stale
# so we check the latest upstream from a directory that does get updated
UPSTREAM_CHECK_URI = "${DEBIAN_MIRROR}/main/b/base-passwd/"

inherit autotools

do_install () {
    install -d -m 755 ${D}${sbindir}
    install -o root -g root -p -m 755 ${B}/update-passwd ${D}${sbindir}/
    install -d -m 755 ${D}${mandir}/man8 ${D}${mandir}/pl/man8
    install -p -m 644 ${S}/man/update-passwd.8 ${D}${mandir}/man8/
    install -p -m 644 ${S}/man/update-passwd.pl.8 \
        ${D}${mandir}/pl/man8/update-passwd.8
    gzip -9 ${D}${mandir}/man8/* ${D}${mandir}/pl/man8/*
    install -d -m 755 ${D}${datadir}/base-passwd
    install -o root -g root -p -m 644 ${S}/passwd.master ${D}${datadir}/base-passwd/
    sed -i 's#:/root:#:${ROOT_HOME}:#' ${D}${datadir}/base-passwd/passwd.master
    install -o root -g root -p -m 644 ${S}/group.master ${D}${datadir}/base-passwd/

    install -d -m 755 ${D}${docdir}/${BPN}
    install -p -m 644 ${S}/debian/changelog ${D}${docdir}/${BPN}/
    gzip -9 ${D}${docdir}/${BPN}/*
    install -p -m 644 ${S}/README ${D}${docdir}/${BPN}/
    install -p -m 644 ${S}/debian/copyright ${D}${docdir}/${BPN}/
}

basepasswd_sysroot_postinst() {
#!/bin/sh

# Install passwd.master and group.master to sysconfdir
install -d -m 755 ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${sysconfdir}
for i in passwd group; do
    install -p -m 644 ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${datadir}/base-passwd/\$i.master \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${sysconfdir}/\$i
done

# Run any useradd postinsts
for script in ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${bindir}/postinst-useradd-*; do
    if [ -f \$script ]; then
        \$script
    fi
done
}

SYSROOT_DIRS += "${sysconfdir}"
SYSROOT_PREPROCESS_FUNCS += "base_passwd_tweaksysroot"

base_passwd_tweaksysroot () {
    mkdir -p ${SYSROOT_DESTDIR}${bindir}
    dest=${SYSROOT_DESTDIR}${bindir}/postinst-${PN}
    echo "${basepasswd_sysroot_postinst}" > $dest
    chmod 0755 $dest
}

python populate_packages:prepend() {
    # Add in the preinst function for ${PN}
    # We have to do this here as prior to this, passwd/group.master
    # would be unavailable. We need to create these files at preinst
    # time before the files from the package may be available, hence
    # storing the data from the files in the preinst directly.

    f = open(d.expand("${STAGING_DATADIR}/base-passwd/passwd.master"), 'r')
    passwd = "".join(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    f = open(d.expand("${STAGING_DATADIR}/base-passwd/group.master"), 'r')
    group = "".join(f.readlines())
    f.close()

    preinst = """#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p $D${sysconfdir}
if [ ! -e $D${sysconfdir}/passwd ]; then
\tcat << 'EOF' > $D${sysconfdir}/passwd
""" + passwd + """EOF
fi
if [ ! -e $D${sysconfdir}/group ]; then
\tcat << 'EOF' > $D${sysconfdir}/group
""" + group + """EOF
fi
"""
    d.setVar(d.expand('pkg_preinst:${PN}'), preinst)
}

addtask do_package after do_populate_sysroot

ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"

PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-update"
FILES:${PN}-update = "${sbindir}/* ${datadir}/${PN}"

pkg_postinst:${PN}-update () {
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$D" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
${sbindir}/update-passwd
}
```

Could it be due to a sporadic event? For example no connection? Or is there something to change inside the file?
I don't understand where the problem is.
On the internet they say that the problem could be the branch but I can't find the branch used inside the file and I don't know which file it's getting from.
Going to the link: https://code.launchpad.net/base-passwd
There is written:

```
There are no branches for base-passwd in Launchpad
```

The link that failed to fetch: https://launchpad.net/debian/+archive/primary/+files/base-passwd_3.5.29.tar.gz
pasted into the browser it works.

So I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Is a sporadic event, I have tested this.